# apply background color to left and right only; exclude middle

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply one background color to the left and the right of my main site content, while keeping the middle header/body/footer sections of the website a different color. In other words, I want the left and right sections of the page to be blue (for example) while the middle (which displays all the content) is white.

I've tried a few things--resulting in a mostly white main section--but if there's no content taking up the rest of the page, the surrounding color fills in the space rather than the white. You can see an example of this issue in the "Welcome!" section.

```css
section, aside, h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
section, aside {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
/*Body styles*/
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1100px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #eff0f6;
}
/*Header styles*/
header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
header #logo {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 5px; 
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
header h1 {
  color: black;
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

header h2 {
  color: black;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
}


/*Navigation styles*/

#nav_menu {
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height:40px;
}

#nav_menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#nav_menu li {
  margin: 0px;
}

#nav_menu li a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
}

#nav_menu li a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #cf2033;
}

.social {
  height: 35px;
  weight; 35px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-left: 2px;
}


/*Section styles*/

section {
  width: 764px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

/*Aside styles*/

aside {
  width: 275px;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

aside h1 {
  font-size: 125%;
}

aside #johnjenkinsphoto1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 275px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
}

aside p {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

/*Footer styles*/

footer {
  clear: both;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 1em;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
 <title>Coach John R. Jenkins | Consultant, Personal Trainer, Speaker</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
      <img src="fitness icon1.png" alt="Title of Website" id="logo" width="80">
      <hgroup>
          <h1>Coach John R. Jenkins</h1>
          <h2>Your Virtual Guide to Wellness, Performance, and Success</h2>
      </hgroup>
      <br>
  </header>
    <nav id="nav_menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="starthere.html">START HERE</a></li>
    <li><a href="consulting.html">CONSULTING</a></li>
    <li><a href="training.html">TRAINING</a></li>
    <li><a href="speaking.html">SPEAKING</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    <a href="http://www.pinterest.com" target="_blank"><img src="pinterest.png" alt="Coach John Jenkins on Pinterest" class="social" align="right"></a>     
    <a href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><img src="instagram.png" alt="Coach John Jenkins on Instagram" class="social" align="right"></a>    
    <a href="http://www.flickr.com" target="_blank"><img src="flickr.png" alt="Coach John Jenkins on Flickr" class="social" align="right"></a>    
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="facebook.png" alt="Coach John Jenkins on Facebook" class="social" align="right"></a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <aside>
      <h1 align="center">About Coach Jenkins</h1><br>
      <img src="coachjohnjenkinsphoto1.png" alt="Photo of Coach John Jenkins" id="johnjenkinsphoto1"><br><br>
      <p>A brief collection of biographical information for Coach Jenkins may go here. <br><br>
       Unfortunately, Coach Jenkins and I are still planning and revising website content. Thus, I am inserting this information as a placeholder for that information once we have finalized everything.
      </p>
  </aside>
  <section>
      <h1>Welcome!</h1>
      <p>In this section, I intend to provide summary information pertaining to the purpose of this website. Such information will first be quickly broken down as follows:
       <ul>
     <li>First piece of summary information goes here.</li>
     <li>Second piece of summary information goes here.</li>
     <li>Third piece of summary information goes here.</li>
     </ul>
     Unfortunately, Coach Jenkins and I are still planning and revising website content. Thus, I am inserting this information as a placeholder for that information once we have finalized everything.
     </p>
  </section>
  <footer>&copy; Copyright 2016 John R. Jenkins</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also put both my HTML and CSS into a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/js_jenkins/oLdo5m7e/

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wrap all of your page content inside one div, add a white background to that, and remove the white background on the individual elements.

Comment: Updated JSFiddle to show you this. Pay attention to the styles of `.wrapper`: https://jsfiddle.net/oLdo5m7e/2/

Comment: your question is not clear and on your fiddle can't find out any `background:blue` property ,can you give an image/demonstration?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if all browser support it, so it might be a good idea to add a simple background color just in case, but I think you are looking for that:

```
body {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, white, white, red);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep the body as `width:100%` and add another div to control the width to `1100px` by

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eff0f6;
}
body > div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```css
section,
aside,
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
section,
aside {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
/*Body styles*/

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eff0f6;
}
body > div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: white;
}
/*Header styles*/

header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
header #logo {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
header h1 {
  color: black;
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
header h2 {
  color: black;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
}
/*Navigation styles*/

#nav_menu {
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 40px;
}
#nav_menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#nav_menu li {
  margin: 0px;
}
#nav_menu li a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
}
#nav_menu li a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #cf2033;
}
.social {
  height: 35px;
  weight;
  35px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-left: 2px;
}
/*Section styles*/

section {
  width: 764px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
/*Aside styles*/

aside {
  width: 275px;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
aside h1 {
  font-size: 125%;
}
aside #johnjenkinsphoto1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 275px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
}
aside p {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
/*Footer styles*/

footer {
  clear: both;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 1em;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Coach John R. Jenkins | Consultant, Personal Trainer, Speaker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <header>
      <img src="fitness icon1.png" alt="Title of Website" id="logo" width="80">
      <hgroup>
        <h1>Coach John R. Jenkins</h1>
        <h2>Your Virtual Guide to Wellness, Performance, and Success</h2>
      </hgroup>
      <br>
    </header>
    <nav id="nav_menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="starthere.html">START HERE</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="consulting.html">CONSULTING</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="training.html">TRAINING</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="speaking.html">SPEAKING</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
        <a href="http://www.pinterest.com" target="_blank">
          <img src="pinterest.png" alt="Coach John Jenkins on Pinterest" class="social" align="right">
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">
          <img src="instagram.png" alt="Coach John Jenkins on Instagram" class="social" align="right">
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.flickr.com" target="_blank">
          <img src="flickr.png" alt="Coach John Jenkins on Flickr" class="social" align="right">
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
          <img src="facebook.png" alt="Coach John Jenkins on Facebook" class="social" align="right">
        </a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <aside>
      <h1 align="center">About Coach Jenkins</h1>
      <br>
      <img src="coachjohnjenkinsphoto1.png" alt="Photo of Coach John Jenkins" id="johnjenkinsphoto1">
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>A brief collection of biographical information for Coach Jenkins may go here.
        <br>
        <br>Unfortunately, Coach Jenkins and I are still planning and revising website content. Thus, I am inserting this information as a placeholder for that information once we have finalized everything.
      </p>
    </aside>
    <section>
      <h1>Welcome!</h1>
      <p>In this section, I intend to provide summary information pertaining to the purpose of this website. Such information will first be quickly broken down as follows:
        <ul>
          <li>First piece of summary information goes here.</li>
          <li>Second piece of summary information goes here.</li>
          <li>Third piece of summary information goes here.</li>
        </ul>
        Unfortunately, Coach Jenkins and I are still planning and revising website content. Thus, I am inserting this information as a placeholder for that information once we have finalized everything.
      </p>
    </section>
    <footer>&copy; Copyright 2016 John R. Jenkins</footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. My previous attempts to use div (not captured in the code I uploaded here) weren't getting me the results I wanted, but your code helped me realize where I went wrong. I appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming i got your question correct:*

You can go with percentage `90%` for body and margin auto and add background to `html` tag like this.

Also changed `section` width to `auto` to prevent overflowing.

```css
html {
  background-color: blue;
}
section,
aside,
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
section,
aside {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
/*Body styles*/

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #eff0f6;
}
/*Header styles*/

header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
header #logo {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
header h1 {
  color: black;
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
header h2 {
  color: black;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
}
/*Navigation styles*/

#nav_menu {
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 40px;
}
#nav_menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#nav_menu li {
  margin: 0px;
}
#nav_menu li a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
}
#nav_menu li a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #cf2033;
}
.social {
  height: 35px;
  weight;
  35px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-left: 2px;
}
/*Section styles*/

section {
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
/*Aside styles*/

aside {
  width: 275px;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
aside h1 {
  font-size: 125%;
}
aside #johnjenkinsphoto1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 275px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
}
aside p {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
/*Footer styles*/

footer {
  clear: both;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 1em;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Coach John R. Jenkins | Consultant, Personal Trainer, Speaker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="fitness icon1.png" alt="Title of Website" id="logo" width="80">
    <hgroup>
      <h1>Coach John R. Jenkins</h1>
      <h2>Your Virtual Guide to Wellness, Performance, and Success</h2>
    </hgroup>
    <br>
  </header>
  <nav id="nav_menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="starthere.html">START HERE</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="consulting.html">CONSULTING</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="training.html">TRAINING</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="speaking.html">SPEAKING</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
      <a href="http://www.pinterest.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="pinterest.png" alt="Coach John Jenkins on Pinterest" class="social" align="right">
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="instagram.png" alt="Coach John Jenkins on Instagram" class="social" align="right">
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.flickr.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="flickr.png" alt="Coach John Jenkins on Flickr" class="social" align="right">
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="facebook.png" alt="Coach John Jenkins on Facebook" class="social" align="right">
      </a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <aside>
    <h1 align="center">About Coach Jenkins</h1>
    <br>
    <img src="coachjohnjenkinsphoto1.png" alt="Photo of Coach John Jenkins" id="johnjenkinsphoto1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>A brief collection of biographical information for Coach Jenkins may go here.
      <br>
      <br>Unfortunately, Coach Jenkins and I are still planning and revising website content. Thus, I am inserting this information as a placeholder for that information once we have finalized everything.
    </p>
  </aside>
  <section>
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <p>In this section, I intend to provide summary information pertaining to the purpose of this website. Such information will first be quickly broken down as follows:
      <ul>
        <li>First piece of summary information goes here.</li>
        <li>Second piece of summary information goes here.</li>
        <li>Third piece of summary information goes here.</li>
      </ul>
      Unfortunately, Coach Jenkins and I are still planning and revising website content. Thus, I am inserting this information as a placeholder for that information once we have finalized everything.
    </p>
  </section>
  <footer>&copy; Copyright 2016 John R. Jenkins</footer>
</body>

</html>
```